Is "traffic sources" still available in Site Analytics?
In the past, when I visited site analytics, there was a link for "Traffic Sources".
I do not see it anymore as of today.
Has this been removed, or did it move somewhere else?

The old link now 404s.

<site>/site-analytics hasn't shown traffic for a long, long time.

I haven't checked in a while.
